# How to convert STL file in JSON using Python

Tags: json, python-2.7, stl-format

I need to convert `stl` file `json` using `python`, is there any way to do this using `python` programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a project that will help you to convert `.stl` files to `JSON`.

[Project GitHub](https://github.com/acgessler/assimp2json)

Also, [here's](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy-stl) a python module called `numpy-stl`. It offers a wide range of functionalities for directly working on `.stl` files.